# Possible to Hack using F12 Developer Tools

Tags: browser, developer-tools

One situation that could apply to my question is when verifying my form using javascript. When the user doesn't fill all possible requirements, the submit button is disabled. If the user filled all required fields, the submit button is enabled, allowing the user to submit the form.

There is a browser feature called Developer Tools that can be accessed by pressing F12. This tool can make changes to the code to help developers debug their problem.

Developer Tools is not only for changing CSS, it also change the HTML values and javascript.

Does Browser Developer Tools can help a user/hacker enable the submit button without filling all the requirements first? Is it possible also to hack websites using Developer Tools?

Answer (score 2):

Front end validations are more of a convenience rather than a security feature. You must have validations on the server side for data integrity and security. You can enable the Submit button and can submit the data by changing CSS/javascript on the browser. It will not be enough to hack website if the server side validations are in place.

Answer (score 0):

> > Disclaimer: This is only for educational reasons, don't use this for practice as in lots of countries hacking is illegal (legal only if hacking was done due penetration testing or have permission)

Well actually this is possible to hack webpages using `F12` which is `Developer Tools`.

If you have knowledge in **`Javascript`** and other website programming languages you can hack by making password and user generator. Then this generator will generate all possible list and using auto-fill hack and auto-submitter (you must create these too) you have chance to bypass security.

> Don't do this! Seriously! Don't do this!